# W10 and switchable graphics

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, switchable-graphics

I have an HP DV6-6170sl, a switchable graphics laptop (AMD Radeon HD 6770M and Intel HD Graphics 3000). Since it came with W7, HP never released new GPU drivers for W8 or W10, but I'm currently running W8.1 with modified drivers found online.
I would like to update tu Windows 10, but I'm afraid I won't be able to switch between the two GPUs anymore.
As anyone successfully updated from W8.1 to W10 on a similar situation?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 3000 has zero support for Windows 10.  Intel barely provided Windows 8.1 support for it.  `HD 6770M` Windows 10 drivers can be found on AMD's website.

Answer (score 0):

You should install latest Intel Graphics Driver first and AMD Catalyst second. After that switchable graphics should work just fine. [AMD Laptop Support](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/LaptopsFAQ.aspx) page contains answers for any other questions you might have about this.

Comment: There are no Windows 10 drivers for the Intel HD Graphics 3000, so the latest drivers for it, wouldn't support Windows 10.

Comment: Then why W7 tells me it is ready to be upgraded to W10 (compatible hardware)?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 3000 has no "official" Windows 10 support but I'm yet to encounter a hardware that works on 8.1 but not on 10. Windows 10 has its flaws like any other OS but driver compatibility isn't one of them.

Comment: Then I'll try to make a system image, update, see if it works, and eventually restore everything. I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

DON'T UPDATE. Nothing works properly: many seconds of black screen before logon screen shows up, sometimes I get just a BSOD, sometimes it works; unable to switch between the two GPUs (I've tried different versions of leshcatlabs drivers, some works, some gives serious problems); desktop and start menu were missing; network takes some minutes before starts working and even then Wi-Fi is unmanageable...
I made a system image before updating, and I had many problems restoring (the only working method was to use a Windows 8 DVD to restore the image). After restoring I tried to uninstall as many software as possible that may be causing problems during update. I re-updated from W8 to W10 and I still had many problems, even if someone was gone.
Then I tried to restore again the W8 system image and the tool says I can't restore cause the image is located on a drive that needs to be formatted. I moved the image to another PC and tried to restore via network: same error message.
I'll try to mount the laptop SSD into PC, format and restore with PC's OS, HOPING it will work!!